# Full Disk Encryption, if my HDD isn't bootable?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I want to find out how to encrypt my HDD, if I plan to boot live operating systems and just use it as storage.
  The operating systems in question will probably be some Debian-distro linux and Windows 8.1, if it matters at all.

Comment: they make "Encrypted Hard Drive Enclosures", or you might find software that can mount the same drive from windows and linux...

Comment: Your best bet is to go with Truecrypt, or at least something that can be mounted by both OSes you want to use.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18751/how-to-encrypt-external-devices-using-a-cross-platform-solution